# AWK: Maintain field spacing like input file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I am emulating my issue in below test file:

```
# cat out 
2014-01-10 18:23:25          0 Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10 18:23:36        503 Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        516 John/ADPTER/CITY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        398 Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38      11117 Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        260 Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:39        466 John/ADPTER/STATE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:40        373 Jim/ADPTER/UNITS MAP.csv
```

This is my Bash variable:

```
# echo $bucket
bucket_name
```

So, in above file, I want the Bash variable value be prefixed to the 4th Field.

This is my desired output:

```
2014-01-10 18:23:25          0 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10 18:23:36        503 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        516 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/CITY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        398 bucket_name/Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38      11117 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        260 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:39        466 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/STATE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:40        373 bucket_name/Jim/ADPTER/UNITS MAP.csv
```

This is what I have tried:

```
# awk -v var=$bucket '{$4=var"/"$4; print}' out 
2014-01-10 18:23:25 0 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10 18:23:36 503 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38 516 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/CITY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38 398 bucket_name/Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38 11117 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38 260 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:39 466 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/STATE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:40 373 bucket_name/Jim/ADPTER/UNITS MAP.csv
```

**Question:**

My `awk` command does what I need, however, it messes up the outfield spacing (separator ??). My Intention is to **just** prefix `bucket_name/` to 4th field and maintain whatever spacing scheme (including right/left justified fields) the input file has.

This is my another attempt:

```
# awk -v var=$bucket 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$4=var"/"$4; print}' out 
2014-01-10  18:23:25    0   bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10  18:23:36    503 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE    MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:38    516 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/CITY    MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:38    398 bucket_name/Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY    MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:38    11117   bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY    MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:38    260 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:39    466 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/STATE   MAP.csv
2014-01-10  18:23:40    373 bucket_name/Jim/ADPTER/UNITS    MAP.csv
```

But it's not helping either.

Thanks.

Comment: In order to keep formatting your awk should not be operating on field basis. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
bucket="bucket_name"
awk --re-interval -v b="$bucket" '{sub(/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}/, 
     "&" b "/")} 1' file
2014-01-10 18:23:25          0 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10 18:23:36        503 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        516 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/CITY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        398 bucket_name/Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38      11117 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        260 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:39        466 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/STATE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:40        373 bucket_name/Jim/ADPTER/UNITS MAP.csv
```

[Online Working Demo](http://ideone.com/DNdrcp)

```
-v b="$bucket"                 # pass a value to awk in variable b
--re-interval                  # Enable the use of interval
                               # expressions in regular expression matching
sub                            # match input using regex and substitute with
                               # the given string
([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3} # match first 3 fields of the line separated by space/tab
 "&" b "/"                     # replace by matched string + var b + /
```

---

**EDIT:** (Thanks to @EdMorton) To make it work with any value in argument (e.g. try both solutions if `bucket="&"`) use:

```
awk --re-interval -v b="$bucket" 'match($0, /([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}/) {
    $0 = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH) b "/" substr($0, RLENGTH+1) } 1' file
```

Comment: This is printing the exact same input file without any prefix to 4th field. Could you modify it please to make it work.

Comment: on my `awk`, it prints exact same input file when I run `awk -v b='bucket_name' '{sub(/([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}/, "&" b "/")} 1' file`. THis is my awk version: `GNU Awk 3.1.8`

Comment: Doesn't work for me either,i get the same as OP, may have an older version of gawk(3.2) like me(doesn't properly support `{3}` notation.

Comment: [Here is working demo of above code](http://ideone.com/DNdrcp) It worked on gnu-awk as well on BSD awk for me. There is nothing awk version specific here.

Comment: `{3}` definitely is awk version specific.

Comment: Some commonly shipped versions of mawk don't understand POSIX character classes (i.e., `[[:blank:]]`); I suspect that's another part of the problem.

Comment: @JID: It has worked on 3 different awk for me. gnu awk and BSD awk on my system and then on online awk

Comment: I can confirm that it fails with mawk 1.3.3.

Comment: Also fails. It's the `{3}` -- it works with `{sub(/([^ \t]+[ \t]+)([^ \t]+[ \t]+)([^ \t]+[ \t]+)/, "&" b "/")} 1`.

Comment: ok so may be `mawk` doesn't like `{3}` but OP has gawk where this should not be a problem. May be `mawk` needs `\{3\}` but I can't test with mawk as I don't have it on my OSX or Linux

Comment: Thanks so much @EdMorton, yes indeed that will work with any value of bucket like `&` or `\\1` etc. Edited answer.

Comment: @anubhava, the newer version with `--re-interval` works for me now. Thanks. +1. Besides, could you briefly explain this oneliner. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure adding explanation in answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have tagged Perl in OP so there is a Perl solution:

```
perl -pe'BEGIN{$var=shift}s,(?:.*?\s+){3}\K,$var/,' "$bucket" out
```

It is technically same solution as the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211574/49197) using `sed` but with the benefit it avoids escaping problems. Shell variable `$bucket` can contain anything.

Comment: Thanks. If you could provide `awk` solution then that will be great. +1 nonetheless. Besides, some explanation of the `perl` one-liner would be really helpful.

Comment: It is technically same solution as the `sed` one but with the help of power of Perl regexp. And it has also some additional safety because I like to avoid escaping issues.

Comment: BTW It is pretty idiomatic Perl so if you have any specific question you can ask.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed.

```
$ bucket='bucket_name'
$ sed "s~^\(\([^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+\)\{3\}\)~\1$bucket/~" file
2014-01-10 18:23:25          0 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/
2014-01-10 18:23:36        503 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/ACCOUNTTYPE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        516 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/CITY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        398 bucket_name/Wendy/ADPTER/COUNTRY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38      11117 bucket_name/Andy/ADPTER/CURRENCY MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:38        260 bucket_name/Sandy/ADPTER/GENDER MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:39        466 bucket_name/John/ADPTER/STATE MAP.csv
2014-01-10 18:23:40        373 bucket_name/Jim/ADPTER/UNITS MAP.csv
```

`[[:blank:]]\+` posix character class which matches any type of horizontal white-space character, one or more times. `[^[:blank:]]\+` POSIX negated character class which matches any character but not of an whitespace one or more times.

Comment: Thanks. If you could provide `awk` solution then that will be great. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky to do in awk, but there is a relevant GNU extension: In gawk, the `split` function takes an optional fourth parameter to save the actual field delimiters for later use. Using that:

```
gawk -v bucket="$bucket" '{ split($0, f, FS, d); d[NF] = ORS; f[4] = bucket "/" f[4]; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) printf("%s%s", f[i], d[i]); }' filename
```

That is:

```
{
  split($0, f, FS, d)             # split line into fields, saving fields in
                                  # the f and delimiters in the d array
  d[NF] = ORS                     # for the newline at the end
  f[4] = bucket "/" f[4]          # fix fourth field
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {      # then print the fields separated by the
    printf("%s%s", f[i], d[i]);   # saved delimiters
  }
}
```

**Addendum:** I cannot really recommend doing this with sed unless the variable comes from a trustworthy source and is guaranteed to not contain metacharacters (otherwise you *will* have code injection problems). That said: a simple way with sed is

```
sed "s|[[:space:]]\+|&${bucket}/|3" filename
```

...which appends `${bucket}` to the third occurrence of `[[:space:]]\+`.

Comment: This needs 4.0+ version of gawk

Comment: This fails with this error: `gawk: fatal: 4 is invalid as number of arguments for split`. BTW, this is the awk that I am Running: `GNU Awk 3.1.8`. However `sed` solution works for this Sample data. +1 nonetheless for your time.

Comment: We only got the 4th arg to split added (after much debate!) in gawk 4.0 as @JID already told you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to insist on awk, it might be simplest to explicitly give a format string:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %10s %s/%s\n", $1, $2, $3, b, $4}' b="$bucket" out
```

Comment: @EdMorton: There is a field after `$4` and that is being skipped here. And don't know how can an answer assume that 3rd field is width=10

Comment: @EdMorton, Well.. what you said should be contributed to the fact that English isn't my primary language. So, yes, I could have phrased question with better words... but the current situation isn't terrible either.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer your English is excellent, the issue was asking for the input formatting to be preserved when you apparently don't need it to be.